# What is the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(n!)^k}{(kn)!}z^n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

What is the radius of convergence of
the power series?
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(n!)^k}{(kn)!}z^n$$

#### Progress

Used the ratio test, but got $0$ from it.

Comment: i couldnt use root test formula.. its giving $\frac \infty \infty$..

Comment: Sometimes, the ratio test also works. Further, you could use Stirling's formula.

Comment: and the ratio test is giving 0..

Comment: I dont know stirlings formula.. is there any other method to find it@DanielFischer

Comment: The ratio test shouldn't give $0$, you must have made a mistake somewhere (I'm assuming $k$ is a fixed non-negative integer). What expressions did you get with the ratio test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(kn+1)(kn+2)\cdots(kn+k)}{(n+1)^k} =
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}k^k\frac{(n+\frac1k)}{n+1}\cdots\frac{(n+1)}{n+1} = k^k.
$$